# Get only what inside of the String.Format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, url

Here is my problem. I'm storing in a hidden field URL on the server side and when the user clicks on a button I'm reading the URL and opening up a pop up window. That thing is the string coming up.

URL(whatever)

How do I get rid of the "URL()" and only get what's inside of the string?

Example:

url(https://www.test.com/cgis/CGT/Reports/CGT_ID_Badge.asp?PersonID=2749)

Here is my code:

```
Dim URL As String = Nothing
URL = String.Format("url(https://www.test.com/cgis/{0}/Reports/CGT_ID_Badge.asp?PersonID={1})", m_User.CompanyCode, m_PersonID)
hfShipping.Value = URL
```

JavaScript:

```
function PrintingReady(sender, args) {

    var test = document.getElementById("<%=hfShipping.ClientID%>").value
    $("#divLoadingMessage").css("display", "block");
    var TryUrl = test;
    printform(TryUrl); // Opening up a popup window with the URL
    //__doPostBack("<%=btnPrintIDBadge.UniqueID %>", "");
 }
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
url(https://www.test.com/cgis/CGT/Reports/CGT_ID_Badge.asp?PersonID=2749)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: it should be a URL I just don't know how to define it on the server side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you initializing the URL variable as a string you don't need to cast same as a URI which I think you were attempting to do.

All you need to do is:

```
string Url = String.Format("https://www.test.com/cgis/{0}/Reports/CGT_ID_Badge.asp?PersonID={1}", m_User.CompanyCode, m_PersonID)
```

Answer (score -1):

It would appear to me that you are getting exactly what you put in:

Try replacing

```
URL = String.Format("url(https://www.test.com/cgis/{0}/Reports/CGT_ID_Badge.asp?PersonID={1})", m_User.CompanyCode, m_PersonID)
```

with

```
URL = String.Format("https://www.test.com/cgis/{0}/Reports/CGT_ID_Badge.asp?PersonID={1}", m_User.CompanyCode, m_PersonID)
```